# parent nav bar link is not active when select children page with conditional user access using routerlink - Angular 15

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-routerlink, routerlinkactive

I want to higlight the nav menu when click that. The problem is when I select child page/link, that parent nav bar menu is not highlight. The problem is routerLinkActive="active" is not active for when select child pages due some conditional user access.

I have added [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }", but not workin due to conditional user access.